# "Undefined symbol" error with my functions when using classes

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that calculates the area and diameter using classes and functions. My issue is that I'm getting an undefined symbol error with my functions. I'm sure it's probably an easy fix ... I just can't figure it out.

(Writing the code on a mac)

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Circle
{
  public:
  int radius;
    
    void printArea();
    void printDiameter();
};

void Circle::printArea()
{
   double area;
 
   area = radius * radius * 3.14159;
   cout<<"A circle with radius "<<radius<<" has an area of "<<area<<endl;
}

void Circle::printDiameter()
{
    int diam;
   diam = radius * 2;
   cout<<"A circle with radius "<<radius<<" has a diameter of "<<diam<<endl;

}

int main()
{
    
   void printArea(Circle);
   void printDiameter(Circle);
   Circle aBigCircle, aLittleCircle;
   aBigCircle.radius = 50;
   aLittleCircle.radius = 4;
   printArea(aBigCircle);
   printDiameter(aBigCircle);
   printArea(aLittleCircle);
   printDiameter(aLittleCircle);
    
}
```

Comment: What symbol is undefined? Please post the complete error message.

Comment: You declared `void printArea(Circle);`  and `void printDiameter(Circle);` functions in `int main()` and called them but did not implement either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I'm sure it's probably an easy fix ... I just can't figure it out." Did you try putting any interesting parts of the error message into a search engine? For example, searching for `undefined symbol c++`? What did you learn this way? In your own words, where the code says `void printArea(Circle);`, what is the intended purpose of this? Similarly, what is the intended purpose of `printArea(aBigCircle);`? Are either of those supposed to have something to do with `void Circle::printArea()`? Why, and how?

Comment: You probably need `aBigCircle.printArea()` instead of `printArea(aBigCircle)`, and to get rid of the extra declarations inside `main`.

Comment: "Undefined symbol: printDiameter(Circle)" and "Undefined symbol: printArea(Circle)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main()
{ 
   // delete printArea() and printDiameter() lines
   // void printArea(Circle);
   // void printDiameter(Circle);
   Circle aBigCircle, aLittleCircle;
   aBigCircle.radius = 50;
   aLittleCircle.radius = 4;
   aBigCircle.printArea();
   aBigCircle.printDiameter();
   aLittleCircle.printArea();
   aLittleCircle.printDiameter();
    
}
```

Delete printArea() and printDiameter() declare in main(). It should fix your problem.

Comment: Good point. will fix

Answer (score 2):

The `printArea()` and `printDiameter()` methods are encapsulated within the `Circle` class, so you must call them from an object.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Circle
{
  public:
    int radius;
    void printArea();
    void printDiameter();
};

void Circle::printArea()
{
   double area;
   area = radius * radius * 3.14159;
   cout<<"A circle with radius "<< radius <<" has an area of "<< area << endl;
}

void Circle::printDiameter()
{
   int diam;
   diam = radius * 2;
   cout<<"A circle with radius "<< radius <<" has a diameter of " << diam << endl;
}

int main()
{
   Circle aBigCircle, aLittleCircle;
   
   aBigCircle.radius = 50;
   aLittleCircle.radius = 4;
   
   aBigCircle.printArea();
   aBigCircle.printDiameter();
   
   aLittleCircle.printArea();
   aLittleCircle.printDiameter();
    
   return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
A circle with radius 50 has an area of 7853.97
A circle with radius 50 has a diameter of 100
A circle with radius 4 has an area of 50.2654
A circle with radius 4 has a diameter of 8
```